# Count number of characters to <span> in string with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, substr

I want to be able to get the character count of up to each `[class^="something-"]`

This is an example of a text block.

```
<div class="intro">
    Lorem dolor sit<br>
    <span class="icon-pin"></span> consectetur<br>
    adiposcing elit, sed do <span class="icon-hand"></span> lorem<br>
    ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

This is what I have so far to get the content into a format so that i can count the characters (minus particular markup, line breaks and white space larger than 1 space)

```
$('[class^="icon-"]', '.intro-title').each(function(index, element){

    var textToIcon = $.trim(
                    $('.intro')
                        .html() // Get HTML code
                        .replace(/[<]p[^>]*[>]/gi, '') // Remove <p> tags
                        .replace(/[<]br[^>]*[>]/gi, '') // Remove <br> tags
                        .replace('&nbsp;', '') // Remove `&nbsp`
                        .replace(/\n+/g, '') // Remove line breaks
                        .replace(/  +/g, ' ') // Remove whitespace larger than one space
                        .replace('&nbsp;', '') // Remove `&nbsp`
                );
});
```

The above JS will output:

```
Lorem dolor sit <span class="icon-pin"></span> consectetur adiposcing elit, sed do <span class="icon-hand"></span lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

I want to know the best way of getting the number of characters until each`span` tag containing a class with `icon-` from the start of the string.

For example the numbers of characters until the first `[class^="icon-"]` is **16** `Lorem dolor sit`

Thanks

Comment: Look at [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) then update your question with your code if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with your existing HTML and JavaScript code like this:

```
    var spansOnly = "Lorem dolor sit <span class=\"icon-pin\"></span> consectetur adiposcing elit, sed do <span class=\"icon-hand\"></span lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
    var reg = /<span[^<]* class=\"[^"]+[^>]*><\/span>/g;
    var textRuns = spansOnly.split(reg);
    var $body = $("body");
    for(var i = 0; i < textRuns.length; i++) {
       $body.append($("<div>" + textRuns[i].length + ": " + textRuns[i] + "</div>"));
    }
```

Here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/don01001100/hyu6fd0j/).

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible to wrap each part of the text in a span it makes this much easier to accomplish:

```js
var element = $('.intro span:first-child').text();
console.log(element.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="intro">
  <span>Lorem dolor sit</span><br>
  <span class="icon-pin"></span> consectetur<br> adiposcing elit, sed do <span class="icon-hand"></span> lorem<br> ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```